# Dragging the textview

Tags: android

I wanted to create a photo captioning app and wanted to put an edittext and then drag the same to put it it on a desired space. Can anyone please recommend a tutorial for dragging a textview using touch.

Answer (score 4):

see this solution

```
tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view1);
tv1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {         

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        layoutParams1 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tv1.getLayoutParams();
       switch(event.getActionMasked())
       {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
        int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();
        if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
            x_cord = windowwidth;
        }
        if (y_cord > windowheight) {
            y_cord = windowheight;
        }
        layoutParams1.leftMargin = x_cord - 25;
        layoutParams1.topMargin = y_cord - 75;
        tv1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
});
```

Comment: if it is useful for you please accept the answer it will be useful for others.

Comment: so if we want to add a caption to the existing image from SD card then , do we need to have database for doing this. or can it be saved directly to the SD card

Comment: this is for dragging the textview..'

Comment: @aav Please accept this answer as it has directly answered your question.

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy I like this answer and it works but I would like to see an example or tutorial which does something similar to Snapchat, or Autodesk Sketch, in that when you drag the text it doesn't re-position the entire TextView onto the center of your finger, but instead is dragged smoothly in the direction that your finger is moving... Would you know where to start with this?